# Calling a bash command via python

Tags: python, bash, global-variables, ipython, glob

I have a command in bash:

```
fslstats /Users/Downloads/ALLSITES/3dROIMaker/network3*_GM.nii.gz -l 1.5 -u 2.5 -V | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

output: 755

If I'm now in python trying to run the same command:

```
 for qq in range (0, 5, 1): 
      lo = glob.glob(path2 + "IM" + path1 + "*_GM.nii.gz")  
      lo = ' '.join(lo)
      lower = qq - 0.5
      upper = qq + 0.5
      subprocess.check_output(['fslstats {} -l lower -u upper -V | cut -d ' ' -f 1'.format(lo)], shell=True)
```

I get this error: 
returned non-zero exit status 1)

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the single quotes around your delimiter by double quotes:

`'fslstats {} -l lower -u upper -V | cut -d " " -f 1'`

That way your not terminating the string before the command ends

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. But I am still getting a value of 0 as output with the python method.  I'm not sure why